# MySQL Error In C# - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near**

I try to use two SQLDataReader at the same time in C#. But there is an error. The error in line:

```
 MySqlDataReader dr3 = cmdd3.ExecuteReader();
 MySqlDataReader dr4 = cmdd4.ExecuteReader();
```

The code:

```
MySqlConnection con1 = new MySqlConnection("Data Source =123.456.78.910; user id = root; password=12345;persistsecurityinfo=True; database=trydata");

con1.Open();

MySqlCommand cmdd3 = new MySqlCommand("Select Count(Distinct(SN) from uat.station where StationNumber = @Station and Status = @status and Date_Time between @DateFrom and @DateTo)", con1);

MySqlCommand cmdd4 = new MySqlCommand("Select Count(Distinct(SN) from uat.station where StationNumber = @Station and Status = @status and Date_Time between @DateFrom and @DateTo)", con1);

for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) //for loop to run query simultaneously 11times and store data in array
{
     if (i == 0)
     {
      cmdd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", "Station 1");
      cmdd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", "Station 1");
     }
     else if (i == 1)
     {
      cmdd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", "Station 2");
      cmdd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", "Station 2");
     }
     else if (i == 2)
     {
      cmdd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", "Station 3");
      cmdd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", "Station 3");
     }
     else if (i == 3)
     {
      cmdd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", "Station 4");
      cmdd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", "Station 4");
     }
     else if (i == 4)
     {
      cmdd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", "Station 5");
      cmdd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", "Station 5");
     }
     else if (i == 5)
     {
      cmdd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", "Station 6");
      cmdd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", "Station 6");
     }
     else if (i == 6)
     {
      cmdd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", "Station 7");
      cmdd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", "Station 7");
     }
     else if (i == 7)
     {
      cmdd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", "Station 8");
      cmdd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", "Station 8");
     }
     else if (i == 8)
     {
      cmdd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", "Station 9");
      cmdd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", "Station 9");
     }
     else if (i == 9)
     {
      cmdd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", "Station 10");
      cmdd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", "Station 10");
     }
     else if (i == 10)
     {
      cmdd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", "Station 11");
      cmdd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Station", "Station 11");
     }

    cmdd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "PASS");
    cmdd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@workorder", TextBox3.Text);
    cmdd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", dateTimeFrom);
    cmdd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTo", dateTimeTo);
                    
    cmdd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "FAIL");
    cmdd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@workorder", TextBox3.Text);
    cmdd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", dateTimeFrom);
    cmdd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTo", dateTimeTo);

    MySqlDataReader dr3 = cmdd3.ExecuteReader();
    MySqlDataReader dr4 = cmdd4.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr3.HasRows && dr4.HasRows)
      {
       while (dr3.Read() && dr4.Read())
       {
         string firstColum = (i + 1).ToString();
         string secondColum = stationName[i]; //pass stations name
         string thirdColum = dr3.GetValue(0).ToString(); //pass data SN PASS to thirdColum
         string fourthColum = dr4.GetValue(0).ToString(); //pass data SN FAIL to fourthColum
         string fifthColum = (Convert.ToInt32(thirdColum) + Convert.ToInt32(fourthColum)).ToString(); //count the total of PASS & FAIL
         string sixthColum = ((Convert.ToInt32(thirdColum) / Convert.ToInt32(fifthColum)) * 100).ToString("F"); //Calculate yield of PASS (pass/total)*100 ..

         DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
         dtable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("No."));
         dtable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Station Name"));
         dtable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Pass SN"));
         dtable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Fail SN"));
         dtable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Total"));
         dtable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Yield Pass"));

         RowValues[0] = firstColum;
         RowValues[1] = secondColum;
         RowValues[2] = thirdColum;
         RowValues[3] = fourthColum;
         RowValues[4] = fifthColum;
         RowValues[5] = sixthColum;

         DataRow dRow;
         dRow = dtable.Rows.Add(RowValues);
         dtable.AcceptChanges();
 
         dataGridView1.DataSource = dtable;
         dataGridView1.DataBind();

         con1.Close();
         }
}
```

Is it means I cannot use two SQLDataReader together with 1 connection string?
I did try set MultipleActiveResultSets=true in web.config aslo but still error remained the same.

Error Image:

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Hi @Seracens, can you provide complete SQLCommand for `cmdd3` in your question? As it mentions there is a syntax error in your query command. Thank you.

Comment: Also share the query that you are firing, it must be related to that

Comment: Hi there @YongShun, I have updated the code. you may see the SQL Command for cmdd3 at line 3

Comment: Hi @RanjitSingh, what do you mean by query firing? Is it a command query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1.0 ISSUE(S)

Your query was close the bracket wrongly for `COUNT()`

```
Select Count(Distinct(SN) from uat.station where StationNumber = @Station and Status = @status and Date_Time between @DateFrom and @DateTo)
```

### 1.1 Solution: Fix incorrect syntax for `COUNT()`

```
Select Count(Distinct(SN)) from uat.station where StationNumber = @Station and Status = @status and Date_Time between @DateFrom and @DateTo
```

---

## 2.0 CONCERN(S)

### 2.1 Concern: Apply DISTINCT in COUNT() might lead to miscalculation

Assume that `SN` is the column in `uat.station` table, to calculate the number of records that appeared in the queried records, you don't need to use `DISTINCT` in your query.

[DISTINCT](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-select-distinct/)

> removes the duplicate values in the column from the result set

Applying `DISTINCT(SN)` in `COUNT` may possibly lead to miscalculation when **SN column IS NOT UNIQUE**.

`COUNT(DISTINCT(SN))`

> If SN column IS **NOT UNIQUE**: Return COUNT = M for **non-duplicate SN value** record(s)

> If SN column IS **UNIQUE**: Return COUNT = N for **ALL** record(s)

`COUNT(SN)`

> Return COUNT = N for **ALL** record(s)

### 2.1 Solution: Remove `DISTINCT()` from query

```
SELECT StationNumber,
    Count(SN) 
FROM uat.station 
WHERE StationNumber = @Station 
  AND Status = @status 
  AND Date_Time between @DateFrom and @DateTo
```

---

### 2.2 Concern: Is it necessary to pass the value into @Station with the loop? And `WHERE StationNumber = @Station` is not correct

Loop to add the value into `@Station` might lead your result output incorrect. Further your `@Station` in WHERE part should use `IN` when comparing multiple values.

**2.2.1 (1st Optional) Solution: Remove @Station params if try to query all Stations & apply `GROUP BY`**

```
SELECT StationNumber,
    Count(StationNumber) 
FROM uat.station 
WHERE Status = @status 
  AND Date_Time between @DateFrom and @DateTo
GROUP BY StationNumber
```

**2.2.2 (2nd Optional) Solution: USE `IN` to compare each value for `@Station` params (needed) & apply `GROUP BY`. [Not recommended but depends on needs]**

```
SELECT StationNumber,
    Count(StationNumber) 
FROM uat.station 
WHERE StationNumber IN @StationNumber
  AND Status = @status 
  AND Date_Time between @DateFrom and @DateTo
GROUP BY StationNumber
```

---

## 3.0 RECOMMENDATIONS

### 3.1 Combine `cmdd3` & `cmdd4` into 1 query for calculation

Both `cmd3` & `cmd4` queries can be combined into 1 query, as both `MySqlCommand` & `MySqlDataReader` are sharing the same query with different `@Status`.

*Note: I use 2.2.1 solution for extending 3.1 recommendation*

```
SELECT
    StationNumber
    , PassCount
    , FailCount
    , TotalCount
    , CAST((PassCount * 100 / TotalCount) AS DECIMAL(5,2)) AS PassPercentage
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        StationNumber,
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 'PASS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PassCount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 'FAIL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FailCount,
        COUNT([Status]) AS TotalCount
    FROM uat.station
    WHERE Date_Time between @DateFrom and @DateTo
    GROUP BY StationNumber
) a
```

---

### 3.2 Stop Using `AddWithValue()`

Using `AddWithValue()` may possibly lead to datatypes mismatched for your Command Parameter(s) and Table column(s). Instead, you need to pass the **exact datatype** in your Command Parameter as the respective database table column.

```
cmdd3.Parameters.Add("@Station", SqlDbType.NVarchar, 50).Value = "Station 1";
cmdd3.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.Varchar, 10).Value = "PASS";
```

Reference: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

---

### 3.3 Apply using block/declaration for `MySqlConnection`, `MySqlCommand` & `MySqlDataReader`

These (implemented with IDisposable interface) will automatically dispose the resources once the process is ended or an exception is triggered.

[Using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)

```
using (MySqlConnection con1 = new MySqlConnection(/* Connection string */))
{
    con1.Open();
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(/* query */, con1))
    {
        // Add Parameter

        using (MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
             // Retrieve value from Data Reader
        }
    }
}
```

[Using declaration for C#8.0](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-declarations-in-c-sharp8/)

```
using MySqlConnection con1 = new MySqlConnection(/* Connection string */);
con1.Open();

using MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(/* query */, con1);
// Add Parameter

using MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// Retrieve value from Data Reader
```

Comment: Yes @YongShun , true my command query missed out on the close bracket. Thank you for spotted that mistake. After I change that the error is gone. But now I got stuck at line GridView1.DataBind(); The error says: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'ID'. Then, I thinking to use your Alternative Solution if I could put it as SelectCommand in sqldatasource then bind the gridview. Is that possible?

Comment: Actually, I have 6 columns No. , Station Name, Pass SN, Fail SN, Total SN, and Yield. How to make sure that Station Name displays accordingly with correct data of PassCount for Pass SN, FailCount for Fail SN, TotalCount for Total SN, and As PassPercentage for Yield. Do I have to add "Distinct(Station)" before the PassCount at your Alternative Solution? sorry asking too much =( I'm newbie

Comment: Hi @Seracens, I suspect in your .aspx (UI) page, the GridView was contained with `ID` in column. The GridView is trying to retrieve the ID column which your DataTable doesn't contains this ID column. You need to revise your GridView for ID column is required. If it is required, be make sure the DataTable need to have ID column.

Comment: You can try to plug-in my alternative solution, but need to make sure that your GridView and DataTable have the exact columns. For "add "Distinct(Station)" before the PassCount at your Alternative Solution",  need to know what is the output you try to achieve. For the result returned from my query, it will return only 1 record as selecting only 1 Station. Thus, `DISTINCT(Station)` is not required. But you can add `StationNumber` or any column you needed in select part. I added into the solution. Maybe you can refer it. Thanks.

Comment: Another concern I would like to raise up, is there necessary to loop adding "Station 1" and so on to SqlParameter for `@Station`? You might get wrong result in this way. If you want to calculate for each Station you can remove the `@Station` param and use `GroupBy`,